# portuguese character õ is read as ? when read from database

Tags: java, character-encoding

portuguese character õ is read as ?  , when we are trying to read the character from database into java file.though UTF-8 is included.Can someone help on this

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: which database platform?

Comment: Check the character code of your `?` character. More likely, it is a `õ`, but the display/IDE/window you're using can't render it properly.

Comment: database used is teradata

Answer (score 1):

**Conversion from special character to question mark `?` happens** in java when converting a java String (Unicode under the hood) to binary data, like OutputStream, using an encoding that cannot represent that character.

One pitfall is, that the encoding often is an optional parameter, defaulting to the platform encoding, which is non-portable.

1. In your case the filling of the database already might have gone wrong. Easily checked (`LIKE '%?%'`).
2. Or the reading. As @Bohemian said, check the char. For MySQL for instance, it does not suffice to have a charset for database/table/column. Also the communication (connection string) needs to indicate an encoding. An internet search will suffice. Teradata should be Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) or UTF-8 capable. Both contain o-tilde.
3. Or the writing, try a String literal `"\u00f5"` which is the `õ`.